# Element-wise multiplication in keras + TF custom loss function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to write a custom loss function using Keras + TensorFlow. I'm getting error while trying to add an element-wise multiplication operation:

```
def new_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    pi = np.pi 
    d = pi/4 + (pi/4) * (y_pred - y_true)

    a = tf.keras.layers.Multiply()([K.sin(d), -K.log(K.cos(d))])
```

Apparently this is wrong, and I'm getting error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_2_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
     [[node dense_2_target (defined at Q:\PycharmProjects\loss_function\custom_loss.py:25) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_164]
```

PS: Do I really need to write these operations in TensorFlow since I'm operating on Tensors? Can I convert 'y_true' and 'y_pred' to Numpy arrays? How to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't use a layer in loss function; instead, simply use `*` to do element-wise multiplication.

Comment: Please provide your full model code to understand what's been done

Comment: I am facign a simmilar problem. But If I use a *, the backend complains of  "unbound variable"

Comment: @OldMan Use the * symbol as today said did the trick for me.